# How to Fix memory leak in Qt 5.6 QWebEngine (markdowneditor example)

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I was testing some of Qt's webenginewidgets examples and tried to compile and run the **Qt5.6.1/Examples/Qt5.6/webenginewidgets/markdowneditor** example.

Without changing anything I went on a executed a good:

```
qmake -tp vc
```

Opened the generated project with Visual Studio 2013 and compiled then ran. The example works fine, but when I look at the RAM memory usage I see that every time I resize the window, the memory increases like crazy. See picture:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? My setup is:

- Windows 10, 64 bit
- Visual Studio 2013
- Qt 5.6.1

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First confirm that you still see the issue in Qt 5.7.0, then file a bug report.

Comment: Good idea. Just tested, same case in Qt 5.7. And just found a Qt bug report describing what appears to be the same situation that was closed because "Cannot Reproduce". Any ideas what to do then?
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47804

Comment: Just filed a new bug report, lets see if they can reproduce. Will come back here if it gets resolved.
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56245